# How to use AVAudioPlayer to play MP4?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, protected

I want to use `AVAudioPlayer` to play MP4 files from iTunes generator. I could use `UIWebView` to play it and it worked, but I want to put an image of my choice on the background of the player instead of the "QuickTime"-logo.

[Here](http://a801.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/059/Music/b9/0d/be/mzi.zqnndbil.aac.p.m4p) is an example of the m4p file I want to play with AVAudioPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, "can someone help me figure out how to use `AVAudioPlayer`," then I'd recommend taking a look at Apple's [avTouch sample app](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/avTouch/index.html), the [documentation for `AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html), and the guide [Getting Started with Audio & Video](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_AudioVideo_iPhone/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

When it happened to me I had a missing '/' on the end of my url.  Adding that cleared me right up.